# Running a batch file by java

Tags: java, batch-file, runtime

I just wanted to run a batch file using java code in win7. I can run .exe files with the code but u know it doesn't work with a batch. Where is the problem? You know even cmd.exe doesn't start with that command. But I can run other exe files, I've tried some. The code is this (with try and catch is that): none of them worked!

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c demo.bat");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("demo.bat");
```

i tried to do work with process and i wrote the code below. it retuened

```
       java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException:process has not exited
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.exitValue(Native Method)
        at Test.Asli.main(Asli.java:38)
```

this is the code:

```
           try{  
                Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
                Process proc= rt.exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"); 
                int b = proc.exitValue();
              //  int exitVal = proc.exitValue();
                //System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);}
              }
              catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                  e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Is that really your code? It can't compile.

Comment: I'm sure this is not the exact code (it has 3 "'s). How does this fail? An error message, an exception, ....? Do you do anything with the `Process` returned by `exec`?

Comment: Yes, where is the problem? What do you get? an exception? What stack trace?

Comment: 1) Be sure to read & implement the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html). 2) Unless the code needs to run in 1.4 or earlier, get the `Process` using a [`ProcessBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

```
String[] cmd = {"cmd.exe", "/c", "demo.bat");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

I always prefer splitting the command and the parameters myself. Otherwise it is done by splitting on space which might not be what you want.

Comment: even this doesn't make any change. no error no exception no alarm and no action! it debugs and ends. nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start demo.bat");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 try {
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:PATH/TO/FILE/yourbatchfile.bat");
 } catch(Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

It even hides the annoying prompt window (if you want that)